# Jquery check if image is loaded

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery callback on image load (even when the image is cached)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached)

Is there a way to check if image is loaded by jquery? I have some images with external src and sometime
src points to 404 page. Is there a way to check if that image is loaded? and then I can remove it from dom otherwise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery has a function to deal with this, take a look at [`.error()`](http://api.jquery.com/error/)

So for example you could attach an [`.error()`](http://api.jquery.com/error/) handler to all images and display something else if there is an error, like the source no longer exists:

```
$('img').error(function() {
    $(this).hide();
}).attr("src", "missing.jpg");
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Scoobler/BhqSS/)

Comment: You've got it backwards - don't hide the image, and you should set the `src` in the callback. See my answer.

Answer (score 6):

[@Scoobler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069126/jquery-check-if-image-is-loaded/6069183#6069183) has the right idea, but the wrong implementation.

```
$(function ()
{
    $('img').error(function()
    {
        $(this).attr('src', 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/THJzu.gif');
    });
});
```

The `.error()` binding **must** take place on document ready - window load is too late.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/EebmC/

Comment: I thought the same, but strangely his demo link works, even in a huge DOM where I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use `error` event like this....

```
$('#imageId')
  .error(function() {
    alert('Something bad happened.')
  })
  .attr("src", "image.gif");
```

Comment: @ Vivek.... ;)  Instead of 'use' use ...'test'. Or we'll suppose you use *alerts* all around your web pages! ;)   This looks like a modifyed copy-paste answer of the previous answer.